# Two divs 50% width as squares

Tags: html, css

How can I make two `div`s like these?

- If the gray area becomes small, the two `div`s maintain the appearance.
- In the red box I can use `box-sizing: border-box;` and `padding: 50% 0;`, but in the blue box I need to put text.

[image]

```css
.c {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.c1 {
  width: 300px;
}
.c2 {
  width: 200px;
}
.w {
  width: 100%;
}
.w div {
  float: left;
}
.i {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.t {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="c c1">
  <div class="w">
    <div class="i"></div>
    <div class="t"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="c c2">
  <div class="w">
    <div class="i"></div>
    <div class="t"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex ... any code and things you tried that did not work  to share aside a screenshot ?

Comment: I put an image because I could not test any code because I did not know where to start haha

Comment: I know it's something simple, but I never had to do something similar to this

Comment: Upload your code to: http://jsfiddle.net/ or simple past it into your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.square {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50% 50% 0 0;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  background: red;
}
.text {
  background: blue;
}
.text > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 50% 0;
  line-height: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="square image"></div>
  <div class="square text">
    <div>text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.square{
    width: 50%;
    
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.square:before{
    content: '\0020';
    padding-top: 100%;
  
    display: block;
}
.boxer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#c1{
    background: salmon;
}
#c2{
    background: lightblue;
}
#image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.centered{
    position: absolute;
  
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  
    text-align: center;
  
    -webkit-transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
       -moz-transform:    -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform:         translate(-50%, -50%);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div class="square">
      <div class="boxer" id="c1">
          <img id="image" src="https://www.archlinux.org/static/vector_tux.864e6cdcc23e.png"/>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="square">
      <div class="boxer"  id="c2">
          <p class="centered">
          You can put your text here!
          I you don't like to have it centered,
          remove class centered!
          </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```